using turf.points to assign each gis coordinate with related property?
i have a set of geo points, such as
let geo_points = [  
   { "lnglat":[100,50], "id": 1 },
   { "lnglat":[100,50], "id": 2 },
   ....
];

by using turf.js, I can transform the geo points with turf points in this method and try to see which points in the predefined geojson
let lnglats = _.map( geo_points, function(item){
    return item.lnglat;
});
let ids = _.map( geo_points, function(item){
    return item.id;
});
let points = turf.points( lnglats  );

let ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon( points , predefined);

the output of turf.pointsWithinPolygon only shows the lnglat without id property.
Seeing the documentation, it can add property to points.
 turf.points( lnglats , ids );

trying the method above only add the same property to each point in lnglat array .
{ 
   type: 'FeatureCollection', features:
       [ {type: 'Feature', properties: [ 1, 2 ], geometry: {…}}
         {type: 'Feature', properties: [ 1, 2 ], geometry: {…}}
       ]
}

what I really need is
{ 
   type: 'FeatureCollection', features:
       [ {type: 'Feature', properties: 1, geometry: {…}}
         {type: 'Feature', properties: 2, geometry: {…}}
       ]
}

how would I assign each point with lnglat and related id
